# Heroku with Node not clearing/updating the node_modules folder for a github based library

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, node-modules

We have a node web project hosted off of Heroku that contains a library hosted on GitHub. We often make changes to the GitHub library.

When we push the updated node web project to Heroku for deployment, it doesn't check if the library on GitHub has been updated.

We're wondering if there is a command that clears the cache/node_modules folder on Heroku to resolve this?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after searching for a while. You have to disable the cache via config and also purge the existing one for old builds. Also I recommend deleting the package-lock.json to clear any issues.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior

https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache